# How to block Facebook ads in Epiphany?

Tags: release-loki, epiphany

Allow advertisements is disabled in Preferences, but some ads, especially Facebook ads, bypass the filter. I've tried adding some custom lists to `/home/.config/epiphany/adblock/filters.list` but they didn't remove the facebook ads. Nothing changed compared with the default easylist.txt.

Answer (score 1):

In my humble opinion, just try to install Firefox from app center or via terminal and use ublock origin and Facebook container plugins in Firefox.

I get rid of the Epiphany in terminal

```
sudo apt remove --purge epiphany
```

Then

```
sudo apt update
```

And installed Firefox

```
sudo apt install firefox
```

Then some clean

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

Problem solved.

By the way read this thread on reddit,. where is explanation that founders of Elementary OS use chrome. Big LOL.
[Videos from YouTube and other sites not playing properly in Epiphany?](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/7z0a6b/videos_from_youtube_and_other_sites_not_playing/)

Answer (score 0):

Open `Epiphany Browser`  Go to settings `Top Right Corner` Click on `Preferences` OR `CTRL + E` Uncheck `Allow Advertisement`  in general Tab to block ads .

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that. I edited my question.